# importing tensorflow 2.0 on google colab. but i am getting error like "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime." while importing it

Tags: tensorflow

I have successfully installed tensorflow 2.0 version

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (2.0.0a0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tf-estimator-nightly<1.14.0.dev2019030116,>=1.14.0.dev2019030115 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.14.0.dev2019030115)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (0.33.6)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tb-nightly<1.14.0a20190302,>=1.14.0a20190301 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (1.14.0a20190301)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (42.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tb-nightly<1.14.0a20190302,>=1.14.0a20190301->tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tb-nightly<1.14.0a20190302,>=1.14.0a20190301->tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.alpha0) (0.16.0)
```

After this when I try to import tensorflow by command

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

11 frames
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

tf2.0 is already installed in colab. Try:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```